# username in URL (JBOSS + primefaces)

Tags: jboss, primefaces

I have a JBoss Application server on which i deployed a primefaces app. I would like to give the user an address like:

```
"username.mysite.com"
"jondoe.mysite.com"
"user2.mysite.com"
```

and username would be its account. So he juste would have to put his password and not username. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can read on mapping subdomains on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862584/programmatically-create-subdomains-with-jboss-and-java), after that is in place it's just about asking a password and doing the auth based on that.